# WPF designtime code

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Does anybody know any pointers to knowledgebase for how to write design-time experience (i.e. VisualStudio 2008 design time) for WPF controls please?

There are loads of references for creating the design-time code for Windows Forms controls, but hardly any for WPF ones.

I have googled a lot for this, but with no good results.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

See the series at http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2007/08/16/adding-menuactions-think-designerverbs-to-cider-s-right-click-contextmenu.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that.But after reading that article, it all sounds very very complicated, and i have completely lost the interest in writing design-time code for my WPF controls. I raelly love Windows Forms way of writing design time code - it is so intuitive to write.